# How do we access board columns/sections through the API?

Tags: asana-api

I've tried to find the answer but no luck. The Asana Developers blog has a post from Feb 2017 states the availability of the Boards API. See here:

https://asana.com/developers/feed/boards-api

But there are almost no details of how to use it. Can you please tell me how we can access board columns and whether or not a project is a Boards view project? Why is this so hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Boards and list projects are very similar in the API.  You access board columns using the [sections endpoint](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/sections):  `GET /projects/project-id/sections`

You can determine if a project is a board or a list by querying the project:  `GET /projects/project-id`.  The JSON response will have a "layout" key with either a "board" or "list" value.

We are working on releasing more board specific documentation.  We hope to have this clearly documented soon.  In the meantime, you can use the sections docs for columns and projects docs for boards.